# CakePHP Association is not working with userdata to userdatatype

Tags: php, cakephp

I am currently developing a webapp containing some userdata. I have the following tables:

users - contains basic userdata.
userdata - contains large amount of different information about the user.
userdatatype - contains definition for the different userdata.

In CakePHP i am using the hasMany association in the user model to retrieve the userdata information (wich works fine) and in the userdata model i want to use the hasOne association to retrieve the corresponding userdatatype information. But this is not working as userdatatype obviously has no userdata_id as it is the definition for the userdata.

I tried to set the foreignKey to false in the hasOne association and work with the condition `'Userdatatype.id => ??'` but i don't know how to access the instance. How do i link this models together without to much overhead in my code?
Do i really need to loop trough the userdata array and establish the connection by hand?

```
public $hasOne = array(
    'Userdatatype' => array(
        'className' => 'Userdatatype',
        'foreignkey' => false,
        'conditions' => array('Userdatatype.id' = WHAT DO I SET HERE?)
    )
);
```

Comment: Why are you not following cakePHP's naming conventions and following your own conventions? Lemme tell you in big race as your projects goes big , you will  be spending `Most` time on doing patches as you did in code as per question. Please read book given by Cakephp itself and interesting part is it is Free , http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/index.html..

Comment: again you partially answered your own question , `userdatatype obviously has no userdata_id as it is the definition for the userdata` , then have userdata_id in userdatatype table .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Tables: users, userdatas, userdatatypes.

users -> id, email, name etc.
userdatas -> id, user_id, data1, data2, data3 etc.
userdatatypes -> id, userdata_id, type

**Model User.php :** 

    public $hasMany = array('Userdata');

**Model Userdata.php :**

    public $belongsTo = array('User');
    public $hasOne = array('Userdatatype');

**Model Userdatatype.php :**

    public $belongsTo = array('Userdata');
```

This should link your models together, if i understood the question correctly.